# How to use CSS selector with space in class name

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I am trying to find CSS elements in a page, containing white space at the end of the class name:

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
page = @agent.get(somepage)
```

Where the tag is:

```
<div class="Example ">
```

When trying:

```
page.search('.Example')
```

the element is not found and when trying:

```
page.search('.Example ') <- space following the name
```

Nokogiri raises an exception:

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '$' after 'DESCENDANT_SELECTOR'
```

Comment: css classes can't have whitespaces, since those are used for descendant selectors

Comment: "When trying: page.search('.Example') the element is not found": This means the element doesn't exist in the HTML.

Comment: @alf CSS classes can't have whitespace, yet they exist in the wild. Not every HTML document is correct but we still have to work with them.

Answer (score 2):

Your implied premise, that a class cannot be found because it contains a space, is incorrect. Class names do not include spaces. Proof:

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

```
html = <<End
  <html>
    <span class="Example ">One</span>
    <span class="Example foo">Two</span>
  </html>
End

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

puts doc.search('.Example')
```

Output:

```html
<span class="Example ">One</span>
<span class="Example foo">Two</span>
```

So I think your HTML document simply doesn't have a class containing `Example` in it. If you provided the sample HTML, this question would have been easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

To find all elements having class attribute ending in whitespace:

```
page.search('*').select{|e| e[:class] =~ /\s$/}
```

Comment: class names cannot include whitespace, as that is the delimiter, e.g. `class="red green blue"` is three distinct classes.

Comment: @Mark Thomas - Agreed but an element's class attribute can end in whitespace and I think that's what he wants to identify.

Comment: Correctly generated HTML doesn't have spaces in classes unless there are multiple classes defined. HTML in the wild might have them even though it's wrong. We still have to work with them both. So, while technically they can't exist, they do because browsers function with them, and the people generating the pages don't care.

Comment: It is valid though. This is really a bug in Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically target the class attribute you can include spaces.  In my case the class value had a space:

```
<p class="Event_CategoryTree category">
```

Here is how I targeted that element using Nokogiri:

```
page.at_css("[class='Event_CategoryTree category']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath instead.
The following code will return all div containers with the class `a class with spaces` :

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
result = doc.xpath('//div[@class="a class with spaces"]')
```